# Git: How to grep code in history and show original file?

Tags: git

I'm grepping code in git history using the following command:

```
git grep "foo" $(git rev-list --all)
```

It's returning a list where each line begins with a king of hash:

```
27a7c352c1d7e5fde63f7c8857900271abc0a626:LogsController.php: $foo = "Hello World!";
c70fab1b7b7e67734839855eff34d744ec1fbcd9:LogsController.php: $foo = "Hello World!";
28a7bfb582e903af5019e2e1eaa1587a7817ec1b:LogsController.php: $foo = "Hello World!";
```

How to view the original full file from one of these hashes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for :

```
git show 27a7c352c1d7e5fde63f7c8857900271abc0a626:Http/Controllers/LogsController.php
```

---

`git show` is mostly know for `git show <commit-id>`, which displays the information of a commit and its diff with its parent, but :

- `git show` also displays the listing of directories ("trees" in git terms) and files ("blobs" in git terms),
- there is a syntax to point to "a file or a directory within a commit", and that syntax is : `<sha>:path/to/target`

For example, try running :

```
# directories :
git show HEAD:
git show 27a7c352c1d7e5fde63f7c8857900271abc0a626:Http/Controllers/

# files :
git show HEAD:config.ini
git show 27a7c352c1d7e5fde63f7c8857900271abc0a626:Http/Controllers/LogsController.php
```